# Assigning HTML text to NSAttributedString throws EXC_BAD_ACESS on global queue

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, multithreading, nsattributedstring

I am assigning HTML text to `NSAttributedString`. This attributed string is then assigned to one of the UILabel in `UitableViewCell in cellForRowAtIndexPath Method`.
 Due to cell reuse `initWithData: method is causing sluggishness at UI`.
 Hence, I made the code to execute on global queue. I am doing something like this:

```
-(void)assignAttrText:(NSDictionary *)dict{

NSDictionary *msgThreadDict = [dict objectForKey:@"messgDict"];
__block DRMessageThreadTableViewCell *cell = [dict objectForKey:@"cell"];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSAttributedString *attributedString =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithData: [[msgThreadDict objectForKey:@"text"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
     options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
     documentAttributes: nil
     error: &err];
    if(err){
        NSLog(@"Unable to parse label text: %@", err);
    }
    else{
        cell.messageTextLabel.attributedText = attributedString;

    }
});
```

Any leads as to what is causing the app to crash with **`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`** at the method:

```
[[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithData: [[msgThreadDict objectForKey:@"text"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
     options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
     documentAttributes: nil
     error: &err];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a `NSData *mydata` object from `[msgThreadDict objectForKey:@"text"]`, then use `[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData: mydata ...`

I think your object is not of `NSData` type, use string then convert to data,  hence `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` .

```
NSString *ceva = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[msgThreadDict objectForKey:@"text"]];  
NSData *mydata = [ceva dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the crash if I am running the code in global queue. But When I do performSelectorOnMainThread: and remove the global queue thing then it works fine but still on cell reuse sluggishness is there.